# Why is it possible to typecast JFrame into a JPanel?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, casting, polymorphism

Here's an example:

```
// set up frame, panel
JFrame container = new JFrame("Game Example");
panel = (JPanel)container.getContentPane();
```

I checked the Java API and both classes implement the same interface so is that and polymorphism the reason why?

Or is it because both classes inherit from the Component class through inheritance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's that the contentPane usually ***is*** a JPanel. Print out the object's class name and see for yourself.

```
System.out.println(container.getContentPane().getClass().getName());
```

And note that you are ***not*** in fact "typecasting a JFrame into a JPanel". The JFrame's contentPane is not the JFrame itself, not hardly.

Comment: I don't think that's the source of the confusion.

Comment: so your contentpane by default is a JPanel then? I did the print out too but why typecast into JPanel? does it have anything to do with polymorphism or inheritance?

Comment: @Nicholas The [static] return type of `JFrame.getContentPane` is `Container`. Is that the confusion?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline The confusion is why container.getContentPane is from  a JPanel class before the type cast to JPanel. Since it is from the JPanel class, why make it redudant to type cast it into a JPanel even though it is already from a JPanel class?

Comment: @Nicholas: It is never *guaranteed* to be a JPanel. Yes be default, the contentPane *is* a JPanel, but you could make it be anything that derives from the Container class, and it will work. That's the beauty of polymorphism.

Comment: @Nicholas So the concept of static typing. Casting (except the completely different feature for primitives) does not change the actual object in any way.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand, thanks Tom and Hovercraft!

Answer (score 1):

The precedence implied by the grammer is:

```
panel = (JPanel)(container.getContentPane());
```

not

```
panel = ((JPanel)container).getContentPane();
```

Note in addition to extending `Component` both, obviously, extend `Object`.

Comment: Yes I notice the inheritance. Thanks for the side information, Tom. But not quite answering the question. =]